# Intuition behind differential operator of order k.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a funtion of class $C^k$ in an open set $U$ and $u\in U$. The differential operator of order $k$ is the function $d^kf(u): \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
d^kf(u)(x)^{(k)} = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k = 1}^{n} \frac{\partial^kf}{\partial x_{i_1}\dots \partial x_{i_k}}(u) x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_k}
$$

My question is what is the idea behind this definition. I see that it generalizes the idea of derivatives, and it even takes the place of the derivatives in Taylor polynomial's formula, but I'd like to know a little more and have a geometrical interpretation in the case $n=2$.

Comment: what is $\delta $ there? Maybe you wanted to type $\partial $ instead? If this is the case then $d^k$ is **a** differential operator of order $k$. The order of a differential operator is given by the maximum degree of the partial derivatives involved in it definition

Comment: @Masacroso Yeah, it was $\partial$ instead of $\delta$, I've just edit my question. I understand the definition formally, but I want to know what concept represents. If we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ of class $\cal{C}^2$ and a point $(x_0,y_0)$, then $d^2 f(x_0,y_0)(x,y)^(2)= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0) (x-x_0)^2+ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0) (y-y_0)^2 + 2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}(x_0,y_0) (x-x_0)(y-y_0)$. What does this expression say about $f$ at $(x_0, y_0)$?

Comment: in general there is not a concept below some mathematical object. The reason why mathematics exists is just due to a lot of mathematical objects there is not known meaning or intuition at all. That is: mathematics is the science of the no intuitive at all, this is way we need formalism to ensure that our results are correct